# Webpack настройка CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack2

Как можно создать новый `chunk profile.js` что бы в нем были только те зависимости которых нету в `bundle`

Файл `Bundle` - это почти все приложение, я хочу оттуда выделить `profile.js` модуль и загрузить когда нужно.
 Я это делал, но у меня тогда profile.js вышел по размеру `1.9 мб` как и `bundle.js`. Т.е. подхватил все зависимости.
Просто зачем мне все зависимости заново в `profile.js` добавлять, если они уже есть в `bundle.js`

У меня как-то вышло это сделать что `profile.js` был 47 kb, но я это прозевал изменяя конфигурацию

```
var glob = require('glob'),
    ngAnnotate = require('ng-annotate-webpack-plugin'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

const prod = process.argv.indexOf('-p') !== -1;

var plugins = [
    new ngAnnotate({
        add: true,
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'profile',
        children: true,
        minChunks: 2,
        async: true
    }),
];

if (prod) {
    plugins.push(
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            beautify: false,
            comments: false,
            compress: {
                sequences: true,
                booleans: true,
                loops: true,
                unused: true,
                warnings: false,
                drop_console: true,
                unsafe: true
            }
        })
    );
}

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: __dirname + '/application/application.js',
        profile: __dirname + '/application/modules/profile.module.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            moment: __dirname + '/node_modules/moment/min/moment'
        },
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['babel-preset-es2015'].map(require.resolve)
                },
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif|jpg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 1
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader'
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};
```