# почему не работает компонент когда модуль загружен

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

Я имею такой модуль `app.profile`

```
import AuthModule from './../auth/auth.module';
import ComplaintModule from './../complaint/complaint.module';

import ProfileBaseController from './controllers/profile-base.controller';
import ProfileService from './services/profile.service';
import ProfileComponent from './components/subcomponents/profile.component';
import HeadProfileComponent from './components/head/profile.component';
import HeadMenuComponent from './components/head/menu.component';
import OrderFoodComponent from './components/subcomponents/order-food.component';
import ReservationInfoComponent from './components/subcomponents/reservation.component';
import OrderInfoComponent from './components/subcomponents/order-info.component';
import MillisecondsFilter from './filters/milliseconds.filter';
import ProfilePageComponent from './components/subcomponents/profile-page.component';
import SimpleCommentComponent from './components/comments/simple.component';
import RatingCommentComponent from './components/comments/rating.component';
import RatingCommentItemComponent from './components/comments/rating-item.component';
import HolderCommentComponent from './components/comments/holder.component';
import CommentProfileComponent from './components/comments/comment.component';
import EstimateComponent from './components/estimate.component';
import InfoProfileComponent from './components/info.component';
import InformationProfileComponent from './components/information.component';
import OrderProfileComponent from './components/order.component';
import ReservationProfileComponent from './components/reservation.component';
import BonusProfileComponent from './components/reservation.component';

import {EMITTER} from './../../application';
import uiNotification from 'angular-ui-notification';
import ngRoute from 'angular-route';
import angular from 'angular';
import Loc from "../../helpers/localization";

export default angular
    .module('app.profile', [
        ngRoute,
        uiNotification,
        AuthModule,
        ComplaintModule
    ])
    .run(ProfileRun)
    .controller('ProfileBaseController', ProfileBaseController)
    .service('ProfileService', ProfileService)
    .component('profile', ProfileComponent())
    .component('headProfile', HeadProfileComponent())
    .component('headMenu', HeadMenuComponent())
    .component('orderFood', OrderFoodComponent())
    .component('reservationInfo', ReservationInfoComponent())
    .component('orderInfo', OrderInfoComponent())
    .component('profilePage', ProfilePageComponent())
    .component('simpleProfileComment', SimpleCommentComponent())
    .component('ratingProfileComment', RatingCommentComponent())
    .component('ratingItemProfileComment', RatingCommentItemComponent())
    .component('holderProfileComment', HolderCommentComponent())
    .component('profileComment', CommentProfileComponent())
    .component('estimateProfile', EstimateComponent())
    .component('infoProfile', InfoProfileComponent())
    .component('informationProfile', InformationProfileComponent())
    .component('orderProfile', OrderProfileComponent())
    .component('reservationProfile', ReservationProfileComponent())
    .component('bonusProfile', BonusProfileComponent())
    .filter('milli', MillisecondsFilter)
    .name;


/** @ngInject */
function ProfileRun(AuthService, $rootScope, Notification, $location) {

    let prefix = '/my-',
        userUrls = [
            prefix + 'profile',
            prefix + 'information',
            prefix + 'bonus',
            prefix + 'reservation',
            prefix + 'order-food',
            prefix + 'testimonials',
        ];

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', (event, to) => {
        if (userUrls.indexOf(to.originalPath) !== -1) {
            loadCss('css/user-profile.css');
            if (to.authorize && to.authorize === true) {
                if (!AuthService.isUser()) {
                    Notification.error(Loc.get('auth').n_not_auth);
                    $location.path('/');
                } else {
                    EMITTER.emit('setTitle', Loc.getRoute('other', 'user-profile'));
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Следующим шагом у меня есть отдельный модуль `app.profileRoutes` с роутами для этого модуля `app.profile`.

```
import ngRoute from 'angular-route';
import angular from 'angular';

export default angular
    .module('app.profileRoutes', [
        ngRoute,
    ])
    .config(ProfileConfig)
    .name;

/** @ngInject */
function ProfileConfig($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/my-profile', {
            template: `<info-profile></info-profile>`,
            name: 'profile',
            authorize: true,
            resolve: {
                module: () => {
                    import('./profile.module.js').then(module => {
                        angular.module('app').requires.push(module.default);

                    })
                }
            }
        })
        .when('/my-information', {
            template: `<information-profile></information-profile>`,
            name: 'information',
            authorize: true
        })
        /*.when('/my-bonus', {
         template: `<bonus-profile></bonus-profile>`,
         controllerAs: 'profile',
         name: 'bonus',
         authorize: true
         })*/
        .when('/my-reservation', {
            template: `<reservation-profile></reservation-profile>`,
            name: 'reservation',
            authorize: true
        })
        .when('/my-order-food', {
            template: `<order-profile></order-profile>`,
            name: 'order-food',
            authorize: true
        })
        .when('/my-testimonials', {
            template: '<estimate-profile></estimate-profile>',
            name: 'testimonials',
            authorize: true
        });
}
```

Собственно суть в чем, я переписал этот модуль на компоненты, и хочу что бы       при переходе на эти роуты с помощью resolve, загрузить динамически модуль с этими компонентами для роутов.
Я загрузил, но компонент, например `<info-profile></info-profile>` не сработал на роуте `/my-profile`

`ocLazyLoad` не предлагать, не подходит, `webpack` сам на этапе сборки делают отдельный `bundle` с неконтролированным именем файла.
Если кто-то предложит мне сделать несколько точек входа, то я пытался это [сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658730/webpack-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-commonschunkplugin), но не вышло.